# Infinite move object on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, mouseover, move

I'm trying to create a feature where when you mouseover an object, another object begins to move continuously until you mouseout. For some reason in my code it stops after the first 10 pixels, which is this,

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshuaWaheed/7df29/

```
$("a").mouseover(function(){

    $("div").animate({

        "margin-left": "+=" + 10 + "px"

    });

});
```

How can I make it run continuously, while on mouseover only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.animate`, because it's not designed for this. You can move it yourself by altering the CSS in a `setInterval` loop:

```
$("a").mouseover(function () {
    // store the interval ID on the DOM element itself
    $(this).data('tc', setInterval(function () {
        $("div").css({
            "margin-left": "+=1"
        });
    }, 20) // milliseconds
    );
});
$("a").mouseout(function () {
    // clear the interval ID
    clearInterval($(this).data('tc'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/5QJTT/

Comment: Why do this? `parseInt($('div').css('margin-left'),10) + 1` when `+= 1` does the same thing?

Comment: "Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading `+=` or `-=` sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property." - http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: It's the same for CSS. "As of jQuery 1.6, `.css()` accepts relative values similar to `.animate()`. Relative values are a string starting with `+=` or `-=` to increment or decrement the current value. For example, if an element's padding-left was 10px, `.css( "padding-left", "+=15" )` would result in a total padding-left of 25px." - http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Good to know. I never realized they added that. Updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try to do a clever recursion here,

```
$("a").mouseover(function () {
    stop = false;
    animate()
});

$("a").mouseout(function () {
    stop = true;
    $("div").stop();
});

function animate() {
    if (stop) { return; }
    $("div").animate({
        "margin-left": "+=" + 10 + "px"
    }, animate);
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/7df29/1/)

Comment: You can make it smoother by using linear easing: `$("div").animate({ "margin-left": "+=10"},'fast','linear',animate);` -- http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/7df29/2/

Comment: Also, make sure that global `stop` variable isn't going to be used anywhere else on your page.

Answer (score -1):

Try if this works :

```
var over = false;
$("a").mouseover(function(){

   over = true;
   while(over == true)
   {
       $("div").animate({

           "margin-left": "+=" + 10 + "px"

       });
    }
});

$("a").mouseout(function(){

   over = false;
});
```

Comment: Never use while for animations.